# How to control path in vue build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to vue.js and I'm trying to setup a page inside an existing app. The new vue.js is inside /reservation subfolder on the root of the app.

I can run the app on http://localhost:8081/ but that isn't terribly useful.

I need to run it on a path on the server so ajax works.

But when I build it, I get the following file in /reservation/dist:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
   <title>reservation</title>
   <link href="/css/app.a765918f.css" rel="preload" as="style">
   <link href="/js/app.ca0f4db6.js" rel="preload" as="script">
   <link href="/js/chunk-vendors.86fea692.js" rel="preload" as="script">
   <link href="/css/app.a765918f.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <p>Hello world</p><noscript><strong>We're sorry but reservation doesn't work properly without
      JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/js/chunk-vendors.86fea692.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.ca0f4db6.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It needs to have **/reservation/dist** prepended to the paths, or I need some way of having the build put the files at the root without colliding with existing folders. This is probably not going to be the final way we do this, but I need to have something to make this work while we are trying out the framework.

Answer (score 0):

In your `vue.config.js` add the `publicPath` prop to your `module.exports`

For example, if you have this as your module.exports

```js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}
```

Modify it to

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/sub-folder/',
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}
```

I also would add in a way to check if you are running in development mode, and if you default back to running in the root directory.

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath:  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/sub-folder/'
    : '/',
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}
```

If you are using vue router then you *may* also need to add the `base` prop to your router instance. For example if your `router/index.js` file looks like this:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

You would need to modify it so it looks like this:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  base:"sub-folder",
  routes
})

export default router
```

For more info please see [this article](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)